# Executing insert operation with autoinc fields with FireDac TFDCommand and retieving generated values

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'm trying to do an insert operation in a table with autoinc fields, and I'm using FireDac TFDCommand for that. So, the record is getting successfully inserted on db, but how to get the generated values for autoinc fields?

Obs: TFDConnection let me get the last auto gen. value, but the table generates two autoinc fields. I could get the primary key and select the record in db, but it's gonna be another call to db and I need to prevent it.

Any idea?

Comment: The two fields is filled but I need the generated value of both fields. Whem I use TFDCommand and call executesql, no recordset is returned. So how to get that values?

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Some databases have non standard SQL extensions that allows you to get some field values after the statement execution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way seems to parse `TFDConnection.Messages` property, after the insert occurs. Some DBMS, like SQL Server, return messages as an additional result set.

To enable messages processing, set `ResourceOptions.ServerOutput` to `True`.

If messages coming from your database server you use doesn't returns any last inserted key information, I fear that the only solution would be another query to retrieve the last ID ...

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of, make a new query just to get that values. Thinking on using datasnap, it's not a good idea to make a query and select records (open dataset) and so include a new record. So, the best way I see is to make sql operations like insert, update... no need to select records from database just to insert a new one, and don't keep them on memory. Maybe my concepts is just wrong, but in performance operations I think this is the best solution.